# Hide or show image based on column values

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm working on a report in which I need to show or hide images based on the values of a column. E.G: if the value 18 doesn't exist in the "Details" section, the image 18 must be hidden as described in the attached photo

[image]

I tried to use an array in which I inserted the values of the column I need to use. This is the supress expression I tried to use.

```
shared numbervar array MyArray;
MyArray:=makearray({MyTable.MyColumn});
local numbervar i;
local booleanvar result = true;
for i:=1 to ubound(MyArray)
do
  if (MyArray[i] = 17) then 
  result := false;
result
```

I realize that the images aren't hidden because I'm working on the Page header and I can only access the first line of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're suppressing the images in the page header, you're limited to simple aggregate functions and won't be able to use variables, running totals, etc.

It's not hard but it is tedious because you'll have to create one new formula for each value.

```
//@CheckValue1
if {table.value}=1 then 1 else 0

//@SuppressionValue1
// If this evaluates to 'true' anywhere in your report, including the PH,
// you know value 1 does not appear in your report
maximum({@CheckValue1})=0
```